# Android webview problems with Portrait

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have this code in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

I know that my screen is now locked in `portrait` mode. But is there away to don't use `portrait` mode lock? So my users can view stuff in the other mode without that the app is rested to start screen(index.html)

Comment: If I understand well, you're looking for a way to prevent WebView reloading when screen orientation is changed ?

Comment: Yes correct that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

when savedInstanceState != null

Try:

```
     if (savedInstanceState == null)
      {
      web.loadUrl(webURL);
      }
```

Also you  need the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState override.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  web.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of questions about WebView on StackOverflow lately, so I decided to investigate to find a precise answer that works.

I created a project with a single MainActivity that contains a WebView.

Here are the conditions you have to satisfy to prevent WebView from reloading when rotating the screen :

1. Make the host activity handle configuration changes itself. In my tests, I discovered that you need to set at least those 3 flags :
   `orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize`
2. Set a `WebChromeClient` and a `WebViewClient` or the page loading will be delegated to the user's default browser.

I tested it on the following configurations :

- Nexus 5X with Android Oreo (API 26)
- Virtual Nexus 5X with Android Marshmallow (API 23)
- Virtual Nexus 4 with Android Kit Kat (API 19).

Note that the behavior of WebView before API 19 might be completely different.

Feel free to add any required condition in my post if you found any.